# How to dump the entire gradle build environment to logs?

Tags: gradle

Gradle builds on our CI build machine are coming out differently from builds on our engineers local machines. Clearly there is a difference in the environment that goes beyond the version of gradle and java (since these are identical). This page describes various places where build environment may be adjusted: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html.

To debug this issue I want to log all system environment variables and all external gradle properties so that I can compare the environments. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I found a partial answer, for gradle properties there is a builtin task that prints them all called `properties`. I added that to the dependency tree of my build dynamically by adding this to my build.gradle:

```
preBuild {
  dependsOn tasks.getByName("properties")
}
```

Now it prints all the properties before starting the build.